# I want to create a blurred button and un-blur it on hover

Tags: html, css, button, transition, css-filters

I'm trying to create a button that has a blurred normal state. 
On hover the button should un-blur. I have two problems here:

1. The copy is blurred also which I don't want. I only want the buttons background to be blurred.
2. The blur is cut off on the bottom of the button.

Here you'll find a test that I already tried:

https://codepen.io/claudio_101/pen/GezJrR

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blur button {
  position:relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  left: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.blur button span{
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
}

.blur button:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="blur">
  <button><span>Send</span></button>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

https://codepen.io/claudio_101/pen/pYGVxg

```
<button>
  <span class="copy">SEND</span>
  <span class="bg"></span>
</button>
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-weight:bold;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  position:relative;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.copy {
  position: absolute;
  top:16px;
  left:34px;
  z-index:10;
  color: white;
}

.bg {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1.5s ease;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

button:hover .bg {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove overflow:hidden from `*`...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.blur button {
  position:relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  left: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.blur button span{
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
}

.blur button:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="blur">
  <button><span>Send</span></button>  
</div>
```

Comment: Does this address not having the text blurred?

Comment: @maxpelic Then move Span out of the button, or add another div.background and blur it.

Comment: @maxpelic thx for the feedback. Tried it again with another background, it works, but seems a bit messy. Now I lose my hover when my cursor is over the span. Any suggestions how I can resolve this. BTW sorry for the newb question. Cheers